# shutdown, reboot, printer setup etc. unavailable to normal user after upgrading debian

Tags: debian, upgrade

I did an upgrade to my Debian Jessie box and after that shutdown, hibernate and suspend options are disabled in the gui. I can not even connect any new wifi connections via Network Manager. Also printer settings can not be set. Why would it happen?

Screenshot is as follows:

[image]
[image]

### Partial Solution

[This](http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.se/2012/05/howto-give-network-manager-sufficient.html) article solved the network manager issues except for handling 3G connections.